# How to include an image when creating a record in DatoCMS

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

My app successfully submits single line text via the javascript client as follows. I don't understand how to actually send the image data. The accepted fields for a single asset don't seem to mention actual image data.

It looks like it takes multiple http requests to pull this off, but once again, where does my file input data go?

---- updated ----

Looks like the image must be uploaded first enable to get an ID, which is used when creating a new record. You cannot upload an image and text at the same time.

I'm currently getting this error:
[image]

Reference: [DatoCMS - adding pictures to new records](https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-management-api/resources/item/create#adding-pictures-to-records)
[Uploadng assets](https://community.datocms.com/t/upload-image-with-new-record-from-node-client/1823)

```
const { SiteClient } = require("datocms-client")
const client = new SiteClient("API_KEY")


export default async function createProfile({ firstName, lastName, email, profileImage, slug}) {

  console.log("@createUpload", profileImage)

  async function createUpload(profileImage) {
    const path = await client.createUploadPath(profileImage);
    const upload = await client.uploads.create({
      path,
      author: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
      copyright: "2021",
      defaultFieldMetadata: {
        en: {
          alt: profileImage.name,
          title: profileImage.name,
          focalPoint: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
          },
          customData: {
            watermark: true,
          },
        },
      },
    })

    console.log(upload)

  // this is the next step 
  // const record = await client.items.create({
  //   itemType: "679748",
  //   firstName,
  //   lastName,
  //   email,
  //   slug
  // })

  }

  createUpload(profileImage)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to DatoCMS docs I think your `createRecord` function should look like:

```
const { SiteClient } = require("datocms-client")
const client = new SiteClient("API_KEY")
export default async function createRecord({ firstName, lastName, email, profileImage, slug}) {
    console.log('@createProfile',profileImage)

  // here you are creating the path for local image
  const path = await client.createUploadPath(profileImage); 

  // you can then use the returned path to create a new upload:
  const upload = await client.uploads.create({ path });

  const record = await client.items.create({
    itemType: "679748",
    path, // alternatively use upload
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    slug
  })
  return record
}
```

The documentation is not clear enough in how the asset needs to be structured, you may need to:

```
  const record = await client.items.create({
    itemType: "679748",
    profileImage: {
      // in this case we're just passing the upload ID, as the
      // asset's defaults for alt, title, etc. are fine:
      uploadId: upload.id,
    },
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    slug
  })
```

The answer is strictly linked to your content model but based on [create an Upload in Node](https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-management-api/resources/upload/create#create-an-upload-in-nodejs) and [adding pictures to records](https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-management-api/resources/item/create#adding-pictures-to-records) but in both scenarios you are missing the `createUploadPath` helper, from here, the rest are trials and errors.

Comment: Thank you I've since learned that I need to first upload an image with createUpload, get back an image ID, and then create a new record with createRecord and include the newly uploaded images ID. I am getting this error when I do so: Cannot read property 'onProgress' of undefined. So, I don't know what my error is.

Comment: Can you debug a little bit more? Is it reaching (or ending) the following promise: `const path = await client.createUploadPath(profileImage)`?